# Images are sizzling on mobile HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html

When I load my page, images are displaying correctly, and when I scroll and come back to the images, they appear like this only on mobile :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojVWZ.jpg)

Comment: Can you give more specs? Operating system, browser, paste some code?

Comment: The issue occurs on iPhone X with Safari, the code is only html/css with some SVG and PNG. the error seems to occurs on PNG but I'm not sure cause it recovered a big part of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS in which you want media query.

```
.your_class or img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```